# HTTP Get request with Authentication header groovy

Tags: java, http, groovy, apache-commons-httpclient

I am trying to make a HTTP get request to a URL. I have tried the curl command and it works with my authentication, but in the groovy script I get a NULL response.

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod

def http = new HttpClient();
def get = new GetMethod("https://tect-hello/cit");
def requestHeader=get.setRequestHeader("X-Vault-Token","s.mytoken");
println requestHeader             //NULL
println get.getName();            //GET
println get.getResponseBody()     //NULL
```

CURL command

> curl -H "X-Vault-Token: s.mytoken" -X GET https://tect-hello/cit

I tried the post functionality and it worked.

I am unable to find a way to pass the vault token. I tried both `addRequestHeader` and `setRequestHeader`

Comment: `set` methods usually are `void`, which Groovy maps to null. You haven't ever actually _executed_ the request you built. (Also, if you're _using_ Groovy, then let it work for you; you do not need the semicolons, and you can omit `get`/`set` for standard properties, so `println get.name`.)

Comment: i have also added `http.executeMethod(get)` and now I get status 200. But the response Body to string doesnt work. i have byte array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found how to do the get Method.

```
def get = new GetMethod("URL")
get.setRequestHeader("X-Vault-Token","s.mytoken")
println http.executeMethod(get) // This step is important
println get.getResponseBodyAsString(1000)
```

Hope this helps someone!